# How to pass to the next element when the requested value is not found in a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am quite a beginner on Python. I am trying to extract analytics infos from homebrew packackages APIs through **Request** module. To do so I first dynamically get the urls for each package and then I loop over each url to get the infos I need. The script runs well until the loop stops over the "carina" package. I suppose the stopping is due to the fact the path `package_json['analytics']['install']['30d'][package_name]` is no longer correct in the `[package_name]` part ([the package name in the analytics dictionary becomes "carina --HEAD"](https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/carina.json)).

For this time I would like the loop just pass to the next package and print an error message.

So far I tried to solve it using the following:

```
    try:
        r = requests.get(package_url)
        package_json = r.json()
    exception:
        pass
```

but it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me, please?

#### The script

```
r = requests.get("https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json")
packages_json = r.json()
packages_string = json.dumps(packages_json, indent=2)

results = []

t1 = time.perf_counter()

for package in packages_json:

    package_name = package["name"]
    package_desc = package["desc"]
    package_url = f'https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/{package_name}.json'

    try:
        r = requests.get(package_url)
        package_json = r.json()
    exception:
        pass


    installs_30 = package_json['analytics']['install']['30d'][package_name]
    installs_90 = package_json['analytics']['install']['90d'][package_name]
    installs_365 = package_json['analytics']['install']['365d'][package_name]

    data = {
        "nome": package_name,
        "descrizione": package_desc,
        "analytics": {
            "30d": installs_30,
            "90d": installs_90,
            "365d": installs_365
        }
    }

    results.append(data)

    time.sleep(r.elapsed.total_seconds())


    if r.status_code != 200:
        print (f"Got error for {package_name}")
    else:
        print(f'Got {package_name} in {r.elapsed.total_seconds()} seconds')


t2 = time.perf_counter()


print(f"Finito in {t2-t1} secondi")

with open("packages_info.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(results, f, indent=2)
```

#### The Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-42e0fb795383> in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18     installs_30 = package_json['analytics']['install']['30d'][package_name]
     19     installs_90 = package_json['analytics']['install']['90d'][package_name]
     20     installs_365 = package_json['analytics']['install']['365d'][package_name]

KeyError: 'carina'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are issues in your syntax in the code mentioned above.
Try this -

```
try:
    r = requests.get(package_url)
    package_json = r.json() 
    installs_30 = package_json['analytics']['install']['30d'[package_name]
    installs_90 = package_json['analytics']['install']['90d'[package_name]
    installs_365 = package_json['analytics']['install']['365d'[package_name]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. It still give me the same Error message.

Comment: Please try by adding the lines 18,19,20 in a try except block.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers may be incomplete. While it is true that changing `exception` to `except` will resolve one of the errors, your question specifically asks about checking the path `package_json['analytics']['install']['30d'][package_name]` and moving on to the next package if that raises a key error. To do that, you need your `try/except` call to be wrapped around those particular lines of code. Here is one example:

```
r = requests.get("https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json")
packages_json = r.json()
packages_string = json.dumps(packages_json, indent=2)

results = []

t1 = time.perf_counter()

for package in packages_json:

    package_name = package["name"]
    package_desc = package["desc"]
    package_url = f'https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/{package_name}.json'

    try:
        r = requests.get(package_url)
        package_json = r.json()
        installs_30 = package_json['analytics']['install']['30d'][package_name]
        installs_90 = package_json['analytics']['install']['90d'][package_name]
        installs_365 = package_json['analytics']['install']['365d'][package_name]

        data = {
            "nome": package_name,
            "descrizione": package_desc,
            "analytics": {
                "30d": installs_30,
                "90d": installs_90,
                "365d": installs_365
            }
        }

        results.append(data)


        time.sleep(r.elapsed.total_seconds())


        if r.status_code != 200:
            print (f"Got error for {package_name}")
        else:
            print(f'Got {package_name} in {r.elapsed.total_seconds()} seconds')
    except:
        pass

t2 = time.perf_counter()


print(f"Finito in {t2-t1} secondi")

with open("packages_info.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(results, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: Tks, it's working! Actually I put only the 3 variables installs_30, installs_90, installs_365 inside the try/except block as also [@Samarthya Choudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10775407/samarthya-choudhary) suggested

Comment: That's fine if your exception sets the values of those variables as an effort string or something. If not, on the exception, each of those variables will carry over the value from the previous pass of the loop.

Comment: Ah! I checked the results list and I see that the "carina" package has the same "cargo-completion" (the preceding package) analytics data. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you used the syntax of the following Part wrong:

> ```
> try:
>     r = requests.get(package_url)
>     package_json = r.json()
> exception:
>     pass
> ```

I just ran the code in colab, it worked fine for me, just change `exception` to `except`.

```
import requests
import json
import time

r = requests.get("https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json")
packages_json = r.json()
packages_string = json.dumps(packages_json, indent=2)

results = []

t1 = time.perf_counter()

for package in packages_json:

    package_name = package["name"]
    package_desc = package["desc"]
    package_url = f'https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/{package_name}.json'

    try:
        r = requests.get(package_url)
        package_json = r.json()
    except:
      pass


    installs_30 = package_json['analytics']['install']['30d'][package_name]
    installs_90 = package_json['analytics']['install']['90d'][package_name]
    installs_365 = package_json['analytics']['install']['365d'][package_name]

    data = {
        "nome": package_name,
        "descrizione": package_desc,
        "analytics": {
            "30d": installs_30,
            "90d": installs_90,
            "365d": installs_365
        }
    }

    results.append(data)

    time.sleep(r.elapsed.total_seconds())


    if r.status_code != 200:
        print (f"Got error for {package_name}")
    else:
        print(f'Got {package_name} in {r.elapsed.total_seconds()} seconds')


t2 = time.perf_counter()


print(f"Finito in {t2-t1} secondi")

with open("packages_info.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(results, f, indent=2)
```

**Result**

```
Got a2ps in 0.028664 seconds
Got a52dec in 0.027885 seconds
Got aacgain in 0.028514 seconds
Got aalib in 0.026989 seconds
```

And so on .. Good Luck

Comment: tks, it still stops over "carina" package though.